# Проблема при установке enb через npm, Node js

Tags: node.js

Я пытаюсь установить enb через npm. Сначала что то скачивается, но потом выходят предупреждения, а за ними уже и ошибки. Проискал уже весь интернет, но до сих пор ничего не могу найти.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'puml-link@0.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.17.1', npm: '8.15.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated native-or-bluebird@1.2.0: 'native-or-bluebird' is deprecated. Please use 'any-promise' instead.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.5.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated bem-fs-scheme@1.0.0: Use @bem/fs-scheme instead
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated coa@1.0.3: Please upgrade to 1.0.4 for node 0.10, 0.12, or to 2.0+ for node 4+
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\My folder\Programming\WEB\Learning\test-project\node_modules\bem-components
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-30a83741.cmd
npm ERR! > bem-components@6.0.1 drop-cache
npm ERR! > rm -rf .enb/tmp
npm ERR! "rm" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
npm ERR! ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-27T15_06_18_026Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Зачем вы пытаетесь откопать эту стюардессу?

Comment: Хочу попробовать методологию БЭМ, а там в документации пишут, что нужен enb.

Comment: Не надо. Умерла, так умерла. Идеология ещё как-то живёт, а стек инструментов устарел и не поддерживается.

Comment: Ааа, теперь понятно, почему об этом никто не пишет. Спасибо!